# Is it a problem to go through immigration 3 times in 2 weeks, for really short periods?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens, singapore, sin

My wife and I are taking a few flights later this month that all go via Singapore, but with different carriers for each leg (all booked as separate return trips). Therefore, we have to collect baggage, go through customs/immigration, check-in for the next flight, and go back through customs/immigration again.

We'll be doing this three times over the course of about 2 weeks.

The first time there will be overnight stay in between, which of course isn't that unusual, but the second and third times there'll only be 4 hours in between each. Essentially this means we'll end up with 6 stamps in our passports over a really short period of time.

As Australian citizens we get 90 days visa-free on the spot, so that's not a problem. But are all these entries and exits likely to cause any problems? If so, how should we be prepared?

Comment: Somehow related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38015/why-police-didnt-even-block-me-once-at-the-airport-arrivals

Comment: The only potential problem is if the immigration officer suspects that you're flying in and out of Singapore so frequently because you live in Singapore (while you don't have the correct visa or residence permit).  Your proposed travel pattern does not seem to suggest that you live in Singapore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only real problem you have is the stamps, they will take some space! making your passport full faster than it should be. That's the only problem you might have.

Singapore is a business hub, some businessmen go there on weekly basis or even more than that. Just like Dubai. In addition to that, many airlines transit through there. So, going there more frequent is really ok.

Last thing, you have an onward ticket with a very short layover, that's enough proof of the "intention" of the visit. Really, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I suppose one thing we can do is print out our itinerary so we do have proof of those tickets.